# Stomp Protocol Over WebSocket using Mojolicious in Perl

Tags: perl, websocket, stomp, mojolicious

Currently, we are designing the client application to interact with stomp application over WebSocket using Mojolicious Library in Perl but MOJO doesn't have connect, subscribe and disconnect  methods for  STOMP commands (http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.0.html) and some sample commands provides mentioned below,
we need to design the code for these commands to connect with stomp app

```
$ua->websocket_p('wss://ws.autorentals.com/async_rates')->then(sub {
  my $tx = shift;
  my $promise = Mojo::Promise->new;
  $tx->on(finish => sub { $promise->resolve });
  $tx->on(message => sub {
    my ($tx, $msg) = @_;
    say "WebSocket message: $msg";
    $tx->finish;
  });
  $tx->send('Hi!');
  return $promise;
})->catch(sub {
  my $err = shift;
  warn "WebSocket error: $err";
})->wait;
```

### Commands:

```
CONNECT
login: <username>
passcode:<passcode>

^@
```

---

```
SUBSCRIBE
destination: /queue/foo
ack: client

^@
```

---

```
SEND
destination:/queue/a

hello queue a
^@
```

---

Comment: Was there a question?

Comment: @Grinnz yes bro I can't connect with above URL  through mojo